# Check for active internet connection on login form submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I am using the following code to check if a user has an active Internet connection before submitting the asp.net authentication login form. I only want the client-side form authentication request to go through if the `checkOnline()` script detects an active Internet connection.

This code is working fine, but I hate using `async: false` as it locks up the browser for around 20 seconds until the request times out. Usually I would just add the `timeout` setting, but when using `async: false` this setting is not available.

I've thought about polling the connection every 5 seconds or so, and then adding a disabled attribute to the button, but I feel this is very inefficient and would prefer something that checks when the user submits the login form.

What could be an alternative solution to this?

```
Protected Sub Page_PreInit(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(Me.GetType, "OnSubmitScript", "return checkOnline()")

End Sub


// CHECK ONLINE CONNECTIVITY 

function checkOnline() { 
    isConnected = null; 
    $.ajax({ 
         url: '/',
         async: false 
     }).done(function(isAdmin) { 
         isConnected = true; 
     }).fail(function (e) { 
         isConnected = false; 
         connectionError(); 
     }); 
return isConnected; 
}
```

Comment: I am guessing you want to give the user an appropriate message that he does not have an active internet connection, right? But if this is the case, how he was able to load the login form in the first place?

Comment: @TasosK. Maybe the user has an inconsistent internet connection, so they were connected before but now they have lost the connection.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function checkOnline() { 
    $.ajax({ 
         url: '/',
         async: true 
     }).done(function(isAdmin) { 
         callPostback(); 
     }).fail(function (e) { 
         connectionError(); 
     }); 
$("#lblPrompt").val("Please wait while we verify your Internet connection...");
return false; 
}
```

And then

```
callPostback()
{
    document.forms.form1.submit();
}
```

You need to create lblPrompt and change form1 to proper name if form name is different.

This way user will see the message and your page is not locked and form will be posted when ever internet connection is confirmed.